# Daily calculation of time difference between two Pandas DF rows

Tags: python, pandas

Please see my [for_stack](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/for_stack) dataframe data which was saved via `for_stack.to_pickle('for_stack')`

As per following image I need to add a new column showing the amount of time between Timestamp (09:30) and 'Gap Lower Closed First' which would be 403 minutes for row 1.

I need to only do this for the first row of each day at 09:30 as highlighted.  I would ideally like a new dataframe showing only the 09:30 entry for each day if this is possible?

Thanks for any help.

[image: for_stack image]

I have tried using the following (incorrect code) for a timedelta but just get a `NaT`

```
data['tvalue'] = data.index
data['delta'] = (data['Gap Lower Closed first'] - data['tvalue'])
```

`'Gap Lower Closed first'` is dtype: `datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pandas.TimeGrouper` (i couldn't find the documentation for it) and the [`first` aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html).

Example:

```
In [26]: df = pandas.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01T09:30:00', periods=10, freq='30t') + pd.date_range('2016-01-02T09:30:00', periods=10, freq='30t'), data={'a': np.random.randn(20)})
manage.py:1: FutureWarning: using '+' to provide set union with datetimelike Indexes is deprecated, use .union()
  #!/usr/bin/env python


In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
                            a
2016-01-01 09:30:00 -0.693846
2016-01-01 10:00:00  1.627871
2016-01-01 10:30:00 -0.157882
2016-01-01 11:00:00  0.126959
2016-01-01 11:30:00 -0.865513
2016-01-01 12:00:00  0.042917
2016-01-01 12:30:00 -0.260965
2016-01-01 13:00:00  1.813741
2016-01-01 13:30:00 -1.108866
2016-01-01 14:00:00  1.030709
2016-01-02 09:30:00 -0.063701
2016-01-02 10:00:00 -0.695245
2016-01-02 10:30:00 -0.945378
2016-01-02 11:00:00 -0.394078
2016-01-02 11:30:00  2.005444
2016-01-02 12:00:00  0.920097
2016-01-02 12:30:00  0.329173
2016-01-02 13:00:00  1.951834
2016-01-02 13:30:00 -2.143820
2016-01-02 14:00:00 -0.357149

In [28]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1d')).first()
Out[28]: 
                   a
2016-01-01 -0.693846
2016-01-02 -0.063701
```

In your case, you can do

```
dfg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1d')).first()
dfg['delta'] = dfg['Gap Lower closed first'] - dfg.index
```

Comment: Very nice and I can confirm this works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This I think does what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = {'t1':[datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 10, 9, 30, 0), 
              datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 10, 8, 33, 0)], 
        't2':[datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 11, 10, 34, 0), 
              datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 10, 11, 41, 9)]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('t1')
df['t_diff'] = df.t2 - df.index

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
                                     t2          t_diff
t1
2014-03-10 09:33:00 2014-03-11 10:34:00 1 days 01:01:00
2014-03-10 08:33:00 2014-03-10 11:41:09 0 days 03:08:09


df930 = df[np.logical_and(df.index.hour == 9, df.index.minute == 30)]

In [24]: df930
Out[24]:
                                     t2          t_diff
t1
2014-03-10 09:30:00 2014-03-11 10:34:00 1 days 01:04:00
```

I always use `np.logical_and` on multiple conditions like that, because it interprets it more broadly than I usually mean if I just use `and`, as in this: [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)